# MySQL Regular Expression to match multiple CSV rows containing certain fields in order

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I'd like to use MySQL's `REGEXP` to match multiple numbers of a csv in a MySQL query.

I am trying to identify if a CSV string contains numbers 2 and 9. The order matters in the result. They could be back to back, and be present at the beginning and/or end.

The below CSV strings should all produce positive result:

> 1,**2**,3,4,5,6,7,8,**9**,10
>   **2**,**9**,1,2,3,4,5,10
>   **1**,2,3,5,**9**

These CSV strings should not:

> **9**,2,3,4,5,10 - (2 doesn't exist before 9)
>   **2**,1,2,3,4,5,10 - (9 not present)

I've tried to match what I am expecting in the pattern by the following logic:

1. matching anything or nothing
2. match the number 2 at least one time
3. matching anything or nothing
4. match the number 9 at least one time
5. matching anything or nothing

My expression that is close, but not working is:

```
REGEXP '.*([^0-9][2][^0-9])+.*([^0-9][9][^0-9])+.*'
```

The above expression fails to match if 2 is the very beginning or 9 the very end of the string. Thanks for the input.

Comment: what about "2,9,2" or "9,2,9"? Should these be accepted or discarded?

Comment: Those should both be positive for a result

Comment: and how big can the numbers in the string be? can your string be something like "22,9" ?

Comment: The numbers can be any size typically no more than 4 digits.  IE 1,2,45,6788,3

Comment: There's little if any advantage of doing this kind of thing in SQL, which is why normalisation is the recommended route.

Comment: Thanks strawberry, but you are assuming the data set is not normalized.  That csv string IS the reduced and logical data set to work with.  A giant infrastructure re-write to create data in a format that fits one preg_match query or something else, versus using mysql REGEXP isn't practical nor would I call it the recommended route. Hence the specificity of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL**

Since we're using MySQL `REGEXP`, we can take this approach:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]9[[:>:]]'
```

Assuming we have only one line of CSV in each row, this will match:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,9,1,2,3,4,5,10
1,2,3,5,9
```

And not match:

```
9,2,3,4,5,10
2,1,2,3,4,5,10
20,9,1,2,3,4,5,10
2,19,1,2,3,4,5,10
```

In MySQL, `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match the beginning and ending of a "word", and a `,` is not "part of a word" (but two numbers next to each other are considered a "word" still).

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test WHERE csv REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]9[[:>:]]';
+----+----------------------+
| id | csv                  |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 |
+----+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**PCRE**

I had originally thought this was a PCRE question, but it was a MySQL `REGEXP` question! However, in case someone finds it useful, I'll leave this information about PCRE here.

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/iM2bA7/4) is basically equivalent to the MySQL `REGEXP` above:

```
^.*\b2\b.*\b9\b.*$
```

Using the link above can help you visualize the match.

`\b` is a "word boundary" (and means basically the same thing as `[[:<:]]` or `[[:>:]]` in MySQL), preventing us from matching digits that are part of other numbers.

Note, if you're trying to match the entire multi-line block of text at once, use the `m` PCRE modifier (`PCRE_MULTILINE` flag) so that `^` and `$` anchor at the beginning and end of each line, rather than the whole string.

So, in PHP, we'd use:

```
preg_match('/^.*\b2\b.*\b9\b.*$/', $csvRow);
```

Or:

```
preg_match('/^.*\b2\b.*\b9\b.*$/mg', $wholeCsvFile);
```

Comment: I will test this solution. With real data and queries on my data set. And update if this works for me asap. thanks

Comment: I have tried the regex... without success. I'm guessing because its its not the MySQL flavor of regex. My MySQL statement looks like: $query="WHERE csvline REGEXP '^.*\b2(?:\b[0-9,]+\b)*9\b.*$'

Comment: Ok try my edit! I missed that this was a MySQL regex.

Comment: So while that works in php, it would only work if I looped all the row data of a database table and checked against it with pregmatch.  Its not a viable option for large datasets. Is your php regex easily translatable to a MySQL REGEXP query. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try the edit at the bottom, this should work in MySQL.

Comment: In php myadmin I ran sql 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE csvline REGEXP '^.*[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]([[:<:]][0-9,]+[[:>:]])*[[:<:]]9[[:>:]].*$' and got zero results... tried additional numbers that should have positively matched consistently returned zero results.

Comment: Sorry, what about `REGEXP '^.*[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]([[:<:]][0-9,]+)*[[:<:]]9[[:>:]].*$'`?

Comment: SQL query is still returning 0 results with that last change. :/

Comment: Alright! Just edited with one that works. I was overthinking this. I'll clean up the rest of the post as well.

Comment: Will thank you so much.  Its clean, does exactly what I need it to do. It operates the way i tried designing my regexp in question. I've played with it a bit, and its easy to adjust for additional conditions, for instance, recognizing additional numbers within a csv sequence.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :) Word boundaries are a very useful tool in regexes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(^|(.*\D))2\D(.*[\D]){0,1}9($|\D.*)
```

Check  out the unit tests in this [RegEx-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH7aE1/5)

- `(^|(.*\D))` - beginning of the string or something ending not with 0-9.
- `2` - we need a 2 first!
- `\D(.*[\D]){0,1}` matches ","(needed for 2 and 9 directly after each other like 2,9) or ",...,"
- `9` - we need a 9 after 2.
- `($|\D.*)` - end of the word or something starting not with 0-9

Comment: Is this MySQL-compatible?